# contrast and brightness automatic (for OCR)

Tags: c++, algorithm, ocr, brightness, contrast

I'm looking for an algorithm to adjust automatically contrast and brightness for images that after will be scanned by Tesseract (an OCR engine).

Do you know if is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for a C++ solution? I mean, such adjustments can easily be made into a photoshop action or a "macro" in other photo editing software. If this is not what you want, then ignore my comment. ;)

Comment: if there is any algorithm I can port it in C++, the fact is that I would prefer to don't call another process do it.. I need high performances

Comment: Well, from the top of my head a very simple version would be:
Contrast:
    `output = ((input - 0.5f) * contrast_factor) + 0.5f;`
Brightness:
    `output = brightness_factor * input;`

Assuming your values are between 0.0 and 1.0, and clamping the output. Correct me if I'm wrong. But Throwback1986's suggestion is probably what you should be looking at. :)

Answer (score 3):

Histogram equalization is a good start: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) has a good description of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

### Histogram Equalization

[image: Result with histogram equalization]

### Another algorithm

[image: Result with this algorithm]

[Algorithm of contrast enhancement for the visual document images 
with underexposure](http://lib.semi.ac.cn:8080/tsh/dzzy/wsqk/SPIE/vol6625/66250B.pdf)

Paper by TIAN Da-zeng, HAO Yong, HA Ming-hu, TIAN Xue-dong, HA Yan.